# "key in obj" when obj is a function?

Tags: javascript

I am very new to JavaScript, so I am baffled by the following syntax:

```
if (isFunction(obj)){
  for (key in obj) {
    //do something
  }
 }
```

The `isFunction` method will return true if `typeOf obj=="function"`. But what happens when you it says `key in obj` when `obj` is a function?

Comment: Tip: Use the `var` keyword when declaring variables or they will end up in the global scope. Example: `for (var key in obj)` or declare the variable at the top of the function..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for..in` loop iterates over the enumerable properties of `obj`. Functions are objects, they have their own properties plus inherited properties from their [[prototype]] chain. See ECMA-262 §12.6.4.

Also, don't forget to declare variables that should be kept local.

To address only the enumerable properties on `obj` and not its inherited enumerable properties, it is usual to include a *hasOwnProperty* test:

```
for (var key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    // key is enumerable property of obj, not inherited
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for remembering to use `var` so that `key` doesn't end up in the global scope if used in a function.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript functions are also objects, which means they can have properties. You can do something like this:

```
var f = function () {};
f.a = "foo";
f.b = "bar";
```

If `obj` was `f`, then the `for` loop would iterate with `key` being `"a"` and `"b"`.

Basically, the `for in` loop iterates over all of the properties of an object except those internally marked as non-enumerable (mostly built-in methods and properties).

Answer (score 1):

Functions can also have properties, - the following code is valid:

```
var foo = function() { }
foo.prop1 = 1;
foo.prop2 = "hello";
```

the `for (key in obj)` loop would enumerate prop1 and prop2.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jsfiddle (not sure if this helps) http://jsfiddle.net/FEAzV/